# MVC partial view does not display once hosted on IIS7 but displays in VS2012 dev environment

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I've recently starting using MVC4 in visual studio 2012.

I have a HomeController which has a strongly typed HomeView, within this HomeView i have a partial view which is displayed when a user makes a selection from a DropDownList, the partial view is being shown by an ajax post to a WCF web service. in my dev environment this all works perfectly but once i have uploaded my project to IIS nothing happens when a selection is made from my dropdowns, i opened the development console and im get the following error

> 404 - File or directory not found.The resource you are looking for
>   might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.

I Have read numerous posts, made changes to my server, added the following to my web.config

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
```

and im still getting the 404 error.

Here is action that calls my partial view from within the HomeController.

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Audits(int AuditID, int AccountID)
{
    InspectWebService.AuditClient au = new InspectWebService.AuditClient();
    List<InspectWebService.ct_auditGrid> model = au.getAllUserAudits(
        Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["UserInfo"]["UserID"]), 
        AuditID, 
        AccountID).ToList();
    return PartialView("_Audits", model); 
}
```

And here is my ajax that calls the action which shows the partial view

```
$('#ddlAudits').change(function () {
    var a = $(this);
    var b = $('#ddlAccounts')
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/Audits',
        type: 'post',
        data: { 'AuditID': a.val(), 'AccountID': b.val() },
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function (result) { 
            $('#DivAccounts').html(result).enhanceWithin();
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert(result);
        }
     });
});

$('#ddlAccounts').change(function () {
    var a = $('#ddlAudits');
    var b = $(this)
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/Audits',
        type: 'post',
        data: { 'AuditID': a.val(), 'AccountID': b.val() },
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function (result) { 
            $('#DivAccounts').html(result).enhanceWithin(); 
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert(result);
        }
    });
});
```

I just don't understand why it works in my Dev Environment but not once it has been uploaded to my server.

Comment: Try `url: '/Home/Audits',`

Answer (score 0):

That's because on IIS, it cannot locate your partial view file.

Use @Url.Action instead.

```
$('#ddlAudits').change(function () {
    var a = $(this);
    var b = $('#ddlAccounts')
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Audits","Home")',
        type: 'post',
        data: { 'AuditID': a.val(), 'AccountID': b.val() },
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function (result) { 
            $('#DivAccounts').html(result).enhanceWithin();
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert(result);
        }
     });
});
```